# what is Integration module purpose in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to know Module_Integration purpose in Magento2.

And how it related with Module_Authorization in Magento2

Answer (score 0):

As per Magento depict below definition

Integration enables third-party services to call the Web API by using access tokens. It provides an admin UI that enables manual creation of integrations. Extensions can also provide a configuration file so that an integration can be automatically pre-configured. The module also contains the data model for request and access token management.

Comment: Yes but actually it's not clarify in brief that how authorization connect with it